# Obfuscating a mixed-mode assembly or other means of protection

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, obfuscation, managed-c++

I have created a VSTO application which references a mixed-mode assembly (managed c++ DLL). The main algorithm which needs to be protected exists in this DLL. I have looked at a comprehensive list of .NET obfuscators and I cannot see a free/reasonably cheap version that I can use [1]. Is there any other method besides obfuscation that I can use to protect the DLL's source code, and ultimately the algorithm, from being revealed too easily?

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Scatophaga/Comparison_of_.NET_obfuscators

Comment: I've used [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview) with success.  The eval version merely makes variable names `eval_a` instead of `a`

Comment: When programs like de4dot exist.. obfuscating is basically useless.

Comment: Is there a way to embed it, instead of trying to obfuscate it?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep your code safe is to keep it out of the hands of the users. You can put critical code in a web service, and let the application call it. Unless the user can actually hack the server and get to the code, it's completely safe from decompiling. The downside is that the app needs internet connection to work.

Using an obfuscator will make it a lot *harder* to decompile the code, but it's still *not safe*.

One of the best obfuscators I've used and i highly recommend is **[Confuser](http://confuser.codeplex.com/)**. it's free, easy to use and
at the moment it can't be reversed by 1-click tools that you find on the web like de4dot.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you know if Confuser supports mixed-mode assembly obfuscations?